# Simulator SDCard Database problem

Tags: blackberry

I set a folder as SDCard on simulator. When I try to reach it, throwing FileIOException.

Folder which I set as SDCard: D:\SDCard
DB which I try to reach:      file:///SDCard/Databases/MyDatabase.db

There is also a "Databases" folder under D:\SDCard.

Comment: Is there a message on the FileIOException?  If so, it should explain a little more about the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I give up the struggle with blackberry forever.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the root folder as SDCard/BlackBerry/. So move your database directory into blackberry directory.

Then your path becomes *file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/Databases/MyDatabase.db*

Comment: When using the built-in device storage, you have to be in a specific directory to create and edit files.  The same restriction does not apply to the SDCard